# Mysql cumulative total only working sometimes

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using the following SQL to calculate the running total by date of a data processing function:

```
set @running_total := 0;
select date(event_date), (@running_total := @running_total + count(distinct de.iddocument)) AS cumulative_sum , count(distinct de.iddocument)
from document_event as de
left join document as d on d.iddocument = de.iddocument
where d.iddatastream = 142
and de.event_type = 'RESEARCHED'
and de.update_by_id is not null
group by date(event_date);
```

This SQL has been working perfectly for a year, however on the latest batch of data it no longer calculates the running total, it only displays each days total.

e.g. this is what it does on my older data:

```
+------------------+----------------+-------+
| date(event_date) | cumulative_sum | count |
+------------------+----------------+-------+
| 2015-11-09       |            167 |   167 |
| 2015-11-10       |            329 |   162 |
| 2015-11-11       |            775 |   446 |
| 2015-11-12       |           1151 |   376 |
| 2015-11-13       |           1680 |   529 |
| 2015-11-16       |           2266 |   586 |
| 2015-11-17       |           2837 |   571 |
| 2015-11-18       |           3590 |   753 |
| 2015-11-19       |           4162 |   572 |
+------------------+----------------+-------+
```

and this is what it does on my newest data:

```
+------------------+----------------+-------+
| date(event_date) | cumulative_sum | count |
+------------------+----------------+-------+
| 2016-04-20       |              6 |     6 |
| 2016-04-21       |             91 |    91 |
| 2016-04-22       |            151 |   151 |
| 2016-04-26       |            239 |   239 |
| 2016-04-27       |            203 |   203 |
| 2016-04-28       |            312 |   312 |
| 2016-04-29       |            374 |   374 |
| 2016-05-02       |            368 |   368 |
| 2016-05-03       |            226 |   226 |
+------------------+----------------+-------+
```

How is it possible that the running total is no longer being calculated?

Any ideas appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cumulative sums and aggregations sometimes don't mix.  Try this:

```
select dte,
       (@running_total := @running_total + cnt) AS cumulative_sum, 
       cnt
from (select date(event_date) as dte, count(distinct de.iddocument) as cnt
      from document_event de left join
           document d
           on d.iddocument = de.iddocument
      where d.iddatastream = 142 and
            de.event_type = 'RESEARCHED' and
            de.update_by_id is not null
      group by date(event_date)
      order by date(event_date)
     ) cross join
     (select @running_total := 0) params;
```

Comment: Brilliant, that does the trick, are you able to elaborate why your one works?

Comment: @danspants . . . Alas, I cannot really elaborate.  I have observed that variables sometimes do not work on `group by` queries, because the order of evaluation of the `select` is not in the right order.  Materializing the `group by` in a subquery fixes this problem.